# What does クリンコ mean?

Tags: katakana

I found this sentence in the wild and I cannot find anything about it on the web appart from a David Bowie album that translates Klinko to クリンコ. But what does that word mean in these sentences?:

[image]

And another

[image]

Comment: I'm glad that you found an answer yourself, but this question direly needs a context...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. I'll post it here in case anybody ever else needs it. This is taken from the show Aggretsuko and it's actually a mispronunciation クリック (click)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is unrelated, but クリンコ is a person's name who had a connection to Bowie. [Marcus Klinko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markus_Klinko) is a fashion photographer who took pictures of David Bowie.